# Prolog - building list of terms recursively only including certain terms

Tags: prolog

I am trying to build a list of states recursively only including states that have some sort of condition. I am trying to use a conditional in order to do so but the list is not accumulating through recursive calls.

```
%Base case
epsilon_closure_helper(State, [], States) :-
  States = [State].

%Recursive Case
epsilon_closure_helper(State, Transitions, States) :-
  Transitions = [Head|Tail],
  epsilon_closure_helper(State, Tail, States1),
  Head = next(A, B, Symbol),
  %If test_state true: append State B to States list else append empty list
  test_state(State, A, Symbol) -> append(States1, [B], States) ; 
  append(States1, [], States).

  test_state(TargetState, State, Symbol) :-
    State = TargetState,
    Symbol = epsilon.

   %Example list of Transitions (next). Transitions contain a From state, a To 
    state and Symbol
  [next(state(0, not_accepting), state(1, not_accepting), epsilon), 
   next(state(1, not_accepting), state(3, not_accepting), epsilon)]
```

Even if I change the else condition to States = States1 it doesn't work.  All I want is the States variable to have all the State terms that have the certain condition. Any advice how I can do so or where I am going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!! :)

Edit: So the logic is as follows. If State A from a transition in the transition list matches the target which is supplied in the State variable in the epsilon_closure_helper predicate and the transition Symbol is epsilon I want to add State B from the same transition to the States list.
Transitions are represented as: next(FromState, ToState, Symbol)
States are represented as: State(Number, Accepting)
The accepting variable doesn't matter for this solution.

Comment: Currently, the test for `->` includes all preceding goals.  You need to put round bracket around the actual test up to the end

Comment: Of interest: [Program to Implement NFA with epsilon move to DFA Conversion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-implement-nfa-epsilon-move-dfa-conversion/)

Comment: Of interest: [Implementing finite state machines
and learning Prolog along the way](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~dm/06/winter/684.01/slides/03.pdf)

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks for your help again! Unfortunately the given solution is not exactly what I am looking for. I have added the test_case and a lot more context of what I am trying to accomplish though and let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: @GuyCoder I figured it out it was just the parentheses!

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not give any example input and output and some of the clauses/facts are missing, e.g. `test_state/3` this is a comparable  solution.

When working with threaded variables, i.e. `State`, the customary way to do it is put them at the end of the arguments:

```
epsilon_closure_list([H|T],State0,State)
```

Next with threaded variables the input variable has `0` appended to it and the result variable has no number appended to it. The remaining variables have an incrementing number appended to them.

In your code the tail is processed before each item, which is fine, but when the recursive call is at the end of the clause it is know as [tail-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). When tail-recursion is used, many compilers can optimize the code. This answer uses tail-recursion.

Your code also uses `=/2` which can be factored out to simplify the code, but when learning or writing some new code I too often use it until I have the code working. This answer will have all of the `=/2` factored out.

The use of `append/3` can probably be factored out, and in most cases can, but since you did not give enough example code this answer leaves `append/3` in the answer.

---

Complete code

```
epsilon_closure_list([H|T],State0,State) :-
    (
        valid(H)
    ->
        append(State0,[H],State1)
    ;
        append(State0,[],State1)
    ),
    epsilon_closure_list(T,State1,State).
epsilon_closure_list([],State,State).

valid(a).
valid(c).
valid(d).
```

---

Test cases

```
:- begin_tests(epsilon_closure).

epsilon_closure_test_case([],[]).
epsilon_closure_test_case([b],[]).
epsilon_closure_test_case([b,e],[]).
epsilon_closure_test_case([a],[a]).
epsilon_closure_test_case([a,b],[a]).
epsilon_closure_test_case([a,b,c],[a,c]).

test(1,[forall(epsilon_closure_test_case(Input,Expected_result))]) :-
    epsilon_closure_list(Input,[],State),
    assertion(State == Expected_result ).

:- end_tests(epsilon_closure).
```

---

Example run

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: epsilon_closure ...... done
% All 6 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: How is `append(State0,[],State1)` better than `State1 = State0` ?

Comment: @TomasBy It's not. My answer tries to stay as close as possible to  the posted question so that the OP can compare the working code with her code and make the necessary changes. As I note in the many comments, it would be more helpful if more information was given so that a better answer can be given. The OP uses `append(States1, [], States)`

Comment: Ok, I thought it was an instance of "`=/2` factored out" but now I see it is in the question also.